# Wamp Error:There are no HTTP transports available which can complete the requested request

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I am making a qp website and when i tried to include a twitter plugin I got the following message as error

```
Error: There are no HTTP transports available which can complete the requested request.
```

Then after searching in net I got a solution and I turned on the php_curl in the php extensions

now I am geting a message like this

```
Error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Is there any solution for this issue? I searched everywhere I could. They are all saying the reason for this only rather than how to solve this.Someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is saying that the certificate for the site you are accessing is not verifiable.

If you are using curl you can try these extra parameters to stop curl doing the verification. This of course could leave you open to security issues of course.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to enable the php extension php_curl in Wamp. Click the Wamp icon in your system tray and go to PHP > PHP Extensions > php_curl.

php_curl should have a check mark next to it.

Then click the Wamp icon in your system tray and click put offline, then click Restart All Services.

Then put the server back online and that error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to enable the php extension php_curl in Wamp as well as uncomment the extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini file.
Hope this will resolve your issue of installing plugins in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Go to PHP Extensions then clicked php_curl to enable.